# How to grep over 1 million files?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, ssh, grep

I need to grep about 1 million files.  If there's a better way to do this, let me know.  I was thinking there may be a faster way to do it in perl.

What I'm trying to do is export every line that contains the text `httpsfile` in it.

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
grep 'httpsfile' * >> grepped.txt
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No need to write any code for this - just use xargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ls | xargs grep httpsfile`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in parallel if you want:

```
ls > /tmp/files
parallel -a /tmp/files --xargs -s 100 grep 'httpsfile'
```

Comment: As one (bash) line: `parallel -a <( ls ) --xargs -s 100 grep 'httpsfile'`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a lot of RAM and your on million files are already in the buffer cache, parallelizing won't be of any help given the fact the operation will be I/O bound so here is the fastest still portable (POSIX) way:

```
find . -exec grep httpsfile {} + > grepped.txt
```

Note that unlike the accepted answer solution, using `find` won't fail with oddly named files. Have a look to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Answer (score 2):

Just change `*` to `./` or, whatever is the root directory that contains the 1 million files. You might need to add `-r` as well to make grep recursive and look into nested directories.

`*` in the shell expands out into all the files.